# Create a background process using aiogram

Tags: python-asyncio, telegram-bot

I am trying to send out price alerts for cryptocurrency in a telegram bot I am working on that uses aiogram. The issue I am having is that I am not certain how to start a function as a background, non blocking thread, and then proceed to start the dispatcher. I know how to do this using the standard synchronous telegram bot, but I am confused as to what I am supposed to do with aiogram. I read I can use `dp.loop.create_task` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59502355/how-to-integrate-custom-task-into-aiogram-executor) but that throws an error `Nonetype has no attribute create_task`. Here is the code that I am trying to execute these threads with:

```
print('Starting watchlist process, this needs to run as a non blocking daemon...')
dp.loop.create_task(wl.start_process())
print('Starting broadcaster, this needs to run as a non blocking daemon ... ')
dp.loop.create_task(broadcaster())
print('Starting the bot ...')
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

I simply need the `wl.start_process` and `broadcaster` functions to run in the background. How do I accomplish this?

This is `start_process`:

```
async def start_process(self):
    """
    Start the watchlist process.
    :return:
    """
    threading.Thread(target=self.do_schedule).start()
    await self.loop_check_watchlist()
```

And this is `broadcaster`:

```
async def broadcaster():

count = 0
while True:
    uid_alerts = que.__next__()
    if uid_alerts:
        for i in uid_alerts:
            uid = i[0]
            alert = i[1]
            try:
                if await send_message(uid, alert):
                    count += 1
                await asyncio.sleep(.05)  # 20 messages per second (Limit: 30 messages per second)
            finally:
                log.info(f"{count} messages successful sent.")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created for your the following working example, it demonstrates how to create background task on bot start and how to create background task with the help of user commands.

```py
from aiogram import Dispatcher, executor, Bot
from aiogram import types
import asyncio
import logging

TOKEN = "your token!"


async def background_on_start() -> None:
    """background task which is created when bot starts"""
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        print("Hello World!")


async def background_on_action() -> None:
    """background task which is created when user asked"""
    for _ in range(20):
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print("Action!")


async def background_task_creator(message: types.Message) -> None:
    """Creates background tasks"""
    asyncio.create_task(background_on_action())
    await message.reply("Another one background task create")


async def on_bot_start_up(dispatcher: Dispatcher) -> None:
    """List of actions which should be done before bot start"""
    asyncio.create_task(background_on_start())  # creates background task


def create_bot_factory() -> None:
    """Creates and starts the bot"""
    dp = Dispatcher(Bot(token=TOKEN))
    # bot endpoints block:
    dp.register_message_handler(
        background_task_creator,
        commands=['start']
    )
    # start bot
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_bot_start_up)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    create_bot_factory()
```

Comment: Great, ty - very excellent. May have another question for you concerning intergrating this into what I am working on now.

Comment: @Chev_603 great to hear that it works for you, what's your another question?

Comment: How do I use this with function decorators?

Comment: @Chev_603 what decorators would you like to use? If you are about registering message handler, you do it in `create_bot_factory` in my example

Comment: Yes, exactly - please see sample excerpt code here ... https://termbin.com/f9lp -- I did not write this, but was brought on bored later. Trying to integrate my crypto price alerts with this bot, which is basically a tg bot a friend wrote for the sake of learning python. The entry point is around where I commented # Bot Starts Here  - It was run with asyncio... I would love to see an example

Comment: @Chev_603 just disassemble `create_bot_factory` and you are free to use decorators as they are showed in your example file. I just provided another way to register message in one place instead of using decorators.