# How to make a telegram bot so that it notifies a registered user once an external AI algorithm detects a certain action?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telepot

I am trying to make a telegram bot to establish a user interface for an action detection algorithm.

What I am trying to do is that: Once the algorithm detects a predefined action, it sends related information to my python bot-script and runs it. The script will drive the bot to generate an alert to a registered user.

(Note that the script will be called everytime a detection is made)

The code of the script is as shown below:

```
import argparse
import telepot as tp

# parse arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Send telegram alert when an action is detected')
parser.add_argument('loc', help = 'the location where the action is detected')
parser.add_argument('id', help = 'the camera id that spot this action')
parser.add_argument('img', help = "the url of the frame where the action is detected")
args = parser.parse_args()

# read arguments from command-line
loc = args.loc
cam_id = args.id
img = args.img

# set bot & chat info
bot_token = 'XXXXXXX'
chat_id = YYYY

# define text to be sent
text = "Action Detected!\nLocation: {}\nCamera id: {}".format(loc,cam_id)

# send alert
bot = tp.Bot(bot_token)
bot.sendMessage(chat_id,text)
bot.sendPhoto(chat_id,open(img,'rb'))
```

The issue with this script is that the chat_id is hardcoded into it, which would be a big problem when I want to use this bot to alert a different user.

Is there a decent way that I can get the chat_id within this script while preserving its other functionalities (receiving parameters)?

(If possible: are there any better architectures/methods to fulfill this task?)

Comment: I'd start with using a better maintained module, eg aiogram. Retrieve the input data from a [bot conversation](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html), that will also give you the chatid. Store chatid+data in a database. Add an [async listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67637631/create-a-background-process-using-aiogram) for your algorithm and [broadcast](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/broadcast_example.html) the message to all users registered for a triggered loc/id.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Thank you for your suggestion. I would consider implementing this architecture you advised at my free time. However for the project I am doing, the client seems to be okay to manually input their chat ID, so I guess this issue is now solved.